# Incredibly slow binary access through NHibernate when using IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, nhibernate, iis-express

I've been unable to Google this, possibly cause I can't figure out the right thing to search for. In an MVC3 project I'm working on, I've got a table with an "image" data column on it. This table's accessed through an NHibernate model that maps this column as a byte array. This hasn't been a performance problem when running this on our live server(with regular IIS) or when running with the built in Visual Studio development server. However, trying to run this with IIS Express causes the access to the table to grind to a halt(almost). Seemingly, if I try to access a row that has a binary array that's around 500k in size, the process will start to take 2-3 minutes to complete. Longer if the array's even larger.

Is there some IIS Express configuration that I'm missing that would cause this to happen?

Relevant bits:

- NHibernate 3.1
- Visual Studio 2010 Professional SP1
- Windows 7 Professional x64
- IIS Express 7.5
- Sql Server 2008

The only change being made is the VS project setting for running in IIS Express vs cassini. Other than that, this is all running on the same development machine.

**Update**

After attempting to run a profiler, I discovered that the issue only occurs if IIS Express is being started by Visual Studio. If I run IIS Express outside of VS, the issue does not occur. Regardless of the VS debugger being attached, VS's CPU usage will spike while this problem's occurring. VS is still responsive though.

**Update 2**
This still occurs with IIS Express 8.

Comment: Never heard of such a thing. IIS vs IIS Express should not have anything to do with your database connection. Perhaps the test database your connecting to is the culprit or perhaps your ethernet/internet/wifi speed is the problem...

Comment: Randy: Literally the only difference in this scenario is my project settings. Everything is running on the same machine(both site and database).